# Spark fair scheduling not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scheduling

I'm investigating the suitability of using spark as the back end for my REST API. A problem with that seems to be Spark's FIFO scheduling approach. This means that if a large task is under execution, no small task can finish until that heavy task has finished. According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html a fair scheduler should fix this. However, I cannot notice this changing anything. Am I configuring the scheduler wrong?

scheduler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
  <pool name="test">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <weight>1</weight>
    <minShare>10</minShare>
  </pool>
</allocations>
```

My code:

```
$ pyspark --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR --conf spark.scheduler.allocation.file=/home/hadoop/scheduler.xml
>>> import threading
>>> sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "test")
>>> def heavy_spark_job():
        # Do some heavy work
>>> 
>>> def smaller_spark_job():
        # Do something simple
>>> 
>>> threading.Thread(target=heavy_spark_job).start()
>>> smaller_spark_job()
```

The smaller spark job can only start when the first task of the heavy spark job doesn't need all of the available CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a different pools for your tasks:

> By default, each pool gets an equal share of the cluster (also equal in share to each job in the default pool), **but inside each pool, jobs run in FIFO order**. For example, if you create one pool per user, this means that each user will get an equal share of the cluster, and that each user’s queries will run in order instead of later queries taking resources from that user’s earlier ones.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#default-behavior-of-pools

Also, in PySpark the child thread couldn't inherit the parent thread's local properties, you have to set the pool inside the thread target functions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have implemented fair scheduling correctly. There is a problem in threading as you are not running smaller_spark_job as a thread. Hence, it is waiting for `heavy_spark_job` to get complete first. It should be like below.

`threading.Thread(target=heavy_spark_job).start()`

`threading.Thread(target= smaller_spark_job).start()`

Also, [my post](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-spark-sharing-fairly-between-concurrent-jobs-d1caba6e77c2) can help you to verify FAIR Scheduling from Spark UI.